# In Malachi 3:3 when God says, “He will purify the Levites” was this fulfilled at the cross?

Tags: jesus, malachi, cross

> “Like a refiner of silver he will sit and closely watch as the dross is burned away. He will purify the Levites, the ministers of God, refining them like gold or silver, so that they will do their work for God with pure hearts.” (Malachi 3:3)

I have been going through the Psalms and reading the many prayers of David, Ezra, and etc. I understand that many of them were typeshadows of Christ and his fulfillment at the cross. Whereby I wondered was this (Mal 3:3) fulfilled during Jesus’s death, burial, and resurrection? Furthermore, the raising of the dead saints. Or the tearing of the Veil in the temple. The signs that validated that Jesus was the Son of God unto the Pharisees, Saducees and Jews in its entirety? Or is this of he Acts of the Apostles?

Answer (score 2):

Not at the cross, but at the destruction of the temple - AD 70.  Purifying silver or any metal is done through melting in a furnace.  It burns off the bad elements, and leaves the pure.  Remember Ezek. 22:19-22:

> *"19 Therefore thus saith the Lord God; Because ye are all become dross, behold, therefore I will gather you into the midst of Jerusalem.*
>
> *20 As they gather silver, and brass, and iron, and lead, and tin, into the midst of the furnace, to blow the fire upon it, to melt it; so will I gather you in mine anger and in my fury, and I will leave you there, and melt you.*
>
> *21 Yea, I will gather you, and blow upon you in the fire of my wrath, and ye shall be melted in the midst therof.*
>
> *22 As silver is melted in the midst of the furnace, so shall ye be melted in the midst thereof; and ye shall know that I the Lord have poured out my fury upon you."*  (KJV)

The destruction of the temple in Jerusalem was prophesied through much of the OT, and again in the NT.  Christ told His disciples that the temple would be completely torn down, and the signs to watch for it.  That judgment against the wicked who had crucified Him, and who were persecuting His saints was carried out in the Roman-Jewish war of AD 67 -70, and culminated at the siege of Jerusalem at Passover, Nisan 14 AD 70.  By, late Sept. AD 70, the city and the temple were destroyed.

The believers had already fled Jerusalem and were living in the area around Pella.  The bad "elements" were burned off, and the pure "elements" scattered into the rest of the world.  The gospel spread from Jerusalem, out from "Zion" and is still shouting today (Jer. 25:30; Amos 1:2, 14).

See more at my blog [ShreddingTheVeil.org](https://ShreddingTheVeil.org), especially the posts "Frequent Mistakes - Part III: The Last Day" [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/12/31/frequent-mistakes-part-iii-the-last-day/), "Frequent Mistakes - Part VI: The End of The World, or ?" [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/04/28/frequent-mistakes-part-vi-the-end-of-the-world-or/), and all three parts of "The Signs of the The Feasts" [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/17/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-i-christ-told-the-pharisees-the-time-of-his-return/), [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/), [and here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/08/02/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-iii-the-thief-in-the-night/); as well as many others.

Comment: I would be looking for more precise demonstration that Ezekiel 22 19-22 and Malachi 3:3 definitely relate to what you are asserting they do. You _assert a_ similarity but I cannot see, personally, that you have argued substantially.

Comment: @Nigel, you could read the beginning of Ezek. 22:1-16, esp. vs. 4 & 6 to see the connection to Mal. 3:3.  The priests were those accused from old of feeding off the people, leading them astray (Ezek. 34:8, 10).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers but I did not see the first two scriptures prior to that illustrate the coming of John the Baptist.

I had a chance to read both (Ezek 22 & 34.) Cross-examining both I was so convicted on how strong God was to the Levite’s relative to the civil disobedience of the time. Now I understand that the temple was destroyed not just because of civil disobedience but neglect of Corporate worship and the paying of taxes to the Romans. I forgot where I read this but anyone have any further insight?

Comment: Randy, if you are happy w/ the answer, then pls vote it up and accept it.  But, the ultimate reason YHWH destroyed the temple was that He had to end the old Mosaic animal sacrificial system which He caused to pass away (Heb 8:13).  The blood of bulls and goats would never take away sin, and could not stand once Christ's sacrifice was the only one He will accept.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that part and how it connected. Thank you for all of your revelation.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Jesus and the surrounding story of him are not mentioned or alluded to in any way, shape, or form in the Tanakh (what you call the Old Testament). Dueteronomy 13 or 2 Kings 17 would be the closest to having anything to do with his story.

Durring the time of the death of Jesus, there were 10s of thousands of Jews that were killed in the exact same manner by the Romans.